# Bootstrap 4 legend issue in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 `<legend>` to my login page but it is  fixing at the left of the login screen instead of middle this issue is only in Firefox browser.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'margin-top-20px': true}">
    <fieldset [ngClass]="{'fieldset-header': true}">
        <legend [ngClass]="{'legend': true}">New User?</legend>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce?